$X\cup Y$ dense in $U$ open implies existence of $r\in \partial X\cap \partial Y$, especially $r\in U$
Suppose $U\subset \mathbb{R}$ is an open interval and let $X,Y\subset U$ disjoint subsets that each have positive measure. Furthermore, $X\cup Y$ is dense in $U$. Show that there exists $u\in \partial X\cap\partial Y$, so $u$ is limit of both a sequence in $X$ and another one in $Y$.
What did I try: Tbh, since I was quite lost, I tried contradiction, which did not bring me far. I also thought of using the fact, that $X\cup Y$
dense in $U$
means for all $V\subset U$
open, it holds $(X\cup Y)\cap V\neq\varnothing$
instead of thinking in series. Still, no development.
EDIT There has been a helpful answer, yet there is an important follow-up question.

What have you tried?

Tbh, since I was quite lost, I tried contradiction, which did not bring me far. I also thought of using the fact, that $X\cup Y$ dense in $U$ means for all $V\subset U$ open, it holds $(X\cup Y)\cap V\not=\varnothing$ instead of thinking in series. Still, no development.

Please add what you tried in the question body.

I'm guessing "limes of ... series" is meant to be "limits of ... sequences". And you used MathJax before... why did you not use it for your edit?

I edited the question considering your comments.

First we remove all the isolated points of $X$ and $Y$ to get two new sets $X'$ and $Y'$.
Now consider $d=\text{dist}(X',Y')$.
If $d>0$ then we can get a point $z\in U$ such that $(z-\frac{d}3,z+\frac{d}3)\cap X'=\varnothing$ and $(z-\frac{d}3,z+\frac{d}3)\cap Y'=\varnothing$ but $(z-\frac{d}3,z+\frac{d}3)\subset U$ (as $U$ is convex) a contradiction.
So we must have $d=0$.
Can you do the rest from here?

The associated text and comment to which I was referring were deleted, I guess that means we can delete our comments as well.

(Turning my comment into an answer)
First we remove all the isolated points of $X$ and $Y$ to get two new sets $X'$ and $Y'$.
Now consider $d=\text{dist}(X',Y')$.
If $d>0$ then we can get a point $z\in U$ such that $(z-\frac{d}3,z+\frac{d}3)\cap X'=\varnothing$ and $(z-\frac{d}3,z+\frac{d}3)\cap Y'=\varnothing$ but $(z-\frac{d}3,z+\frac{d}3)\subset U$ (as $U$ is convex),
a contradiction.
So we must have $d=0$.
Can you do the rest from here and find $r\in\partial X\cap\partial Y$?
Now that you get a point $r\in \partial X\cap\partial Y$, you want to make sure $r\in U$.
Suppose not, then $r=a$ or $r=b$, where $U=(a,b)$
Now since $X$ and $Y$ have positive measures so let $k$ be the minimum of their measures. Now consider the new interval $(a+\frac{k}{3},b-\frac{k}{3})$. Repeat the same argument of the original interval. Now whatever new $r'\in \partial X\cap\partial Y$ you get, it will definitely be in $U$

Yes, thank you. However, does it follow that $r\in U$ or do we just get $r\in\overline{U}$?

Because I do need $r\in U$ for my argumentation. And looking at subspace topologies, $\partial X,\partial Y\subset U$ and we already have established $r\in\partial Y \cap \partial Z$. I am not sure about this thinking, though.

@Mathemann Yes we can get a point r that is in U. Suppose U=(a,b). The problem occurs if r=a or r=b. In any case consider a new interval U'=(a+k/3, b-k/3) where k is the minimum of the measures of X and Y. Repeat the argument for this new interval. You will get a new point r'. And r' is definitely in U.

I do understand it correctly that you choose $U'$ in your proposed way such that you guarantee that $X$ and $Y$ still have positive measure in $U'$ in order to repeat your argument on $U'$, right?

@Mathemann Yes. As keeping the positive measure is necessary.
